# Solve An Equation In C++

Tags: c++, lexical-analysis

my question is how would you go about doing a program that solves an equation in C++. For example,

User Input:

```
-5*2+(5+1)+(5-2)
```

Program Output:

```
-1
```

Any code examples, links, help in general is greatly apreciated! :D Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the [help] docs on how to post a proper question.  This is not one of them.

Comment: Search StackOverflow or the web for "c++ calculator"

Comment: What is the right way to ask this question? He basically wants something to get him started, which seems reasonable. How should it be phrased?

Comment: He should indicate whether on not he searched the web and how the web information doesn't correspond.  Why should we answer another calculator question?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - Noblesse oblige, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not about programming in C++, I feel. It is moreso aimed at [lexical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), and more simply, parsing operators and algorithms. A **very** short description of how this would work:

Parse the input into tokens:

```
-5*2+(5+1)+(5-2)
```

becomes

```
MINUS
5
MULTIPLY
2
PLUS
LPAREN
5
PLUS
1
RPAREN
PLUS
LPAREN
5
MINUS
2
RPAREN
```

This is the tokenization. You then need to lex it, which is turning these unrelated tokens into meaningful statements, or sub-statements. Once you have lexed it, you can interpret and return a result.

```
Step A - -5
Step B - A + 2
Step C - 5 + 2
Step D - B + C
Step E - 5 - 2
Step F - D + E
```

Hope this at least gets you started.